# SecCertificateAddToKeychain - Unknown format in import

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain, x509

The funcion SecCertificateAddToKeychain() gives me an error with the certificate I created for testing.

The certificate - TestCert.p12:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -out TestCert.p12
```

The code:

```
NSData  *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (certData)  {
   SecCertificateRef  newCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData (NULL, (CFDataRef)certData);
   if (newCert)  {
      OSStatus  addResult = SecCertificateAddToKeychain (newCert, NULL);
      if (addResult)  {
         NSString  *errStr = SecCopyErrorMessageString (addResult, NULL);
         NSLog (@"Cannot add certificate to keychain: %@", errStr);
      }
   }
}
```

Output: Cannot add certificate to keychain: Unknown format in import.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the .p12 cert manually (from Finder)? Also, you should compare explicitly against `noErr`, not doing so is bad form.

Comment: I can - from Keychain Access app. It asks for the pass and it puts it into keychain, with an red x and a "not trusted" remark. When it comes to noErr, this is a simplified code in as little lines as possible.

Comment: How about importing as DER format instead of PKCS#12? Can you try this with `openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der` ?

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. Amazingly, function SecCertificateGetType() retutns type CSSM_CERT_X_509v3 or 0x03 for both certificates. Now I'll be playing with SecPkcs12Import() and other stuff bartonjs suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SecCertificateCreateWithData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1396073-seccertificatecreatewithdata?language=objc) is only described for X.509 format, not PKCS#12.

For P12 you want [SecPkcs12Import](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1396915-secpkcs12import?language=objc) (which will import to the default keychain by default) or [SecItemImport](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1395728-secitemimport?language=objc) (which will not import private keys unless you explicitly give it the keychain into which to import them -- e.g. [SecKeychainCopyDefault](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1400743-seckeychaincopydefault?language=objc)).

Comment: Thanks. SecPKCS12Import() allowed me to specify the password in options and that may be the reason why SecCertificateAddToKeychain() could not add such certificate. Stefan Arentz told me how to create a .der certificate and I managed to add it to the keychain with SecCertificateAddToKeychain() as well with KeychainAccess utility, both times without a need for a password. Adding .p12 certificate required password in code and with the utility. Looks like I need to learn more about certificates and their differences - .cer, .pem, .der, .p12, ...